# Bash idioms for conditional array append?

Tags: arrays, bash, string-interpolation

I am trying to figure out if there is a shorter way in bash of conditionally appending the value of a variable to an array only if the value is non-null.

I believe the following is correct, but kind of "wordy"

```bash
my_array=()

if [[ "${my_first_var:-}" ]]; then
    my_array+=( "${my_first_var}" )
fi
if [[ "${my_second_var:-}" ]]; then
    my_array+= ( "${my_second_var}" )
fi
```

I'm asking because I'm trying to clean up some code that does this instead:

```
my_array+=( ${my_first_var:-} ${my_second_var:-} )
```

which is a hack that "works" to conditionally append only the non-null values to `my_array`, and is nice because it uses array interpolation, but has the problem that if the string in `my_var` contains a space (or whatever `IFS` is set to) it does something very unintended (appends multiple elements into the array).

I was thinking of this maybe, but I'm not sure if my intent is sufficiently clear.

```
[[ "${my_first_var:-}" ]] && my_array+=( "${my_first_var}" )
[[ "${my_second_var:-}" ]] && my_array+=( "${my_second_var}" )
```

is there a way to conditionally append only non-null values that is terse but is idiomatic and clear?

Comment: What is wrong with the first code you posted? I would write explicitly `[[ -n "${my_var:-}" ]]`. `a shorter way` `[` is shorter than `[[`.  You can do `a=$my_var;[ "$a" ]&&my_array+=("$a")` is shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is

```
my_array+=( ${my_var+"$my_var"} )
```

That will add the value of `my_var` to the array if it is defined, even if it is empty.  If you want to add it only if it is defined and not empty, use

```
my_array+=( ${my_var:+"$my_var"} )
```

Comment: What I really really like about this solution is that it extends naturally to conditionally appending multiple values:
`my_array+=( ${my_first_var:+"$my_first_var"} ${my_second_var:+"$my_second_var"} )`

Comment: I had what the OP was trying to do reversed in my mind, adding to the array if the value was *not* null.